# Probability that the first ball is red, the second is black and the last two are white.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> In a box we have 3 white balls, 4 black balls and 6 red balls. We extract 4 balls, without reintroducing them back. Find the probability that: a. First ball is red, second is black and the next two are red b. The first ball was red, knowing that the second ball was black

Apparently, the probability for case a) is :
$$
\frac{6}{13}*\frac{4}{12}*\frac{3}{11}*\frac{2}{11}
$$

I see where we get these values from ( box 1 has a $\frac{6}{13}$ chance of getting red, box  2 has $\frac{4}{12}$ because 4 white balls and 13-1 balls to choose from, etc.)

The question is:
**Why is the P("a)") = P("box1 -> red")$\cdot$P("box2 -> black")$\cdot$P("box3 -> white")$\cdot$P("box4 -> white") ?**

The formula P(A$\cap$B) = P(A)*P(B) is only available when A and B are independent. In our case, how are this events independent ? Since we don't put the balls back, once we choose the first ball, the outcome of this "first ball" will affect the second one.

Also, sorry in advance for any formatting errors or grammatical mistakes.

Comment: The general formula is $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B\mid A)$ and this is true in all cases, even when the events are not independent such as here.

Comment: Note that $\dfrac{4}{12}$ is not $\Pr(\text{"box2->black"})$.  That would have been $\dfrac{4}{13}$.  Rather, this is $\Pr(\text{"box2->black" | "box1->red"})$ and similar for the rest.

Comment: This post is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: @JMoravitz, Respected Mr. Moravitz, Why do You think that the probability for the case "b" is $\frac{4}{13}$? Explain, please.

Comment: @VadimChernetsov you misread my comment and are misunderstanding what I am talking about.  I am saying $\Pr(\text{"box2}\to\text{black"}) = \frac{4}{13}$.  The answer to part (b) is indeed $\frac{4}{12}$.  The OP's error which I was pointing out was that they incorrectly labeled what the values represented in their post when they wrote "*The question is: Why is the...*"

Answer (score 1):

a. First ball is red, second is black and the next two are red.

$$
\text{Probability}={\frac{{{6}\choose{1}}{{4}\choose{1}}{{5}\choose{2}}}{{{13}\choose{1}}{{12}\choose{1}}{{11}\choose{2}}}}.
$$

$$
\binom{6}{1}\text{ is the quantity of ways to choose 1 any red ball of 6 red balls},
$$

$$
\binom{4}{1}\text{ is the quantity of ways to choose 1 any black ball of 4 black balls},
$$

$$
\binom{5}{2}\text{ is the quantity of ways to choose 2 any red balls of 5 remaining red balls},
$$

$$
\binom{13}{1}\text{ is the quantity of ways to choose 1 any red ball of 13 provided balls},
$$

$$
\binom{12}{1}\text{ is the quantity of ways to choose 1 any black ball of 12 provided balls},
$$

$$
\binom{11}{2}\text{ is the quantity of ways to choose 2 any red balls of 11 provided balls}.
$$

b. The first ball was red, knowing that the second ball was black.

$$
\text{Probability}={\frac{{{4}\choose{1}}}{{{12}\choose{1}}}}.
$$

$$
\binom{4}{1}\text{ is the quantity of ways to choose 1 any red ball of 4 red balls},
$$

$$
\binom{12}{1}\text{ is the quantity of ways to choose 1 any red ball of 12 provided balls}.
$$

Comment: @JMoravitz, Hello, respected Mr. Moravitz! Why do You think that the probability for the case "b" is $\frac{4}{13}$? Explain, please. I think the probability is $\frac{4}{12}$.